# My code is showing error when search is not found with React

Tags: reactjs, api

Please am new to React working with API, when ever the search object is not found, it returned error! Please help me.
I have tried using techniques that I know but it's not working.
What did i need to do or add to make it work and return non-error when search is not returned.

```
function Search() {
const[searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
const[advices, setAdvices] = useState({ slips: [] });
const text = 'Tweet';
const shareText = 'Check https://adviser.surg.sh for more...';
const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
}

let API_URL = `https://api.adviceslip.com/advice/search/`;

const fetchAdvices = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}${searchQuery}`);
    console.log(result.data);
    setAdvices(result.data);
}

const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchAdvices();
}

return (
    <div>
        
        <section>
            <form className='search-box' onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                    <input
                     
                    type='search'
                    placeholder='Search for advice e.g love'
                    value={searchQuery}
                    onChange={onInputChange}
                    />
                    <button className='search-btn' type='submit'>Search</button>
            </form>
            <div className='adviceList'>
                {
                    advices.slips.map((advice, id) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={id}>
                                <div className='advice-card'>
                                    <h2>{advice.advice}</h2>
                                
                                   <p> <Twitter text={text} 
                                        url={advice.advice} 
                                        shareText={shareText} />
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
)
 }

export default Search
```

How can i solve this, please help me with what to do.

Comment: What is the error? which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimal solution is to have the backend to return some sort of data even when the result is not found (ex. a `found` property). Then, use that data to check if there is a result or not. Otherwise, you'd have to do error handling:

```js
const fetchAdvices = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}${searchQuery}`);
    console.log(result.data);
    setAdvices(result.data);
  } catch(e) {
    setAdvices({slips: []}); //or any other value you want to set it to when there's no result returned
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Please how I return the error in case nothing is found?

Comment: If you meant by what to return at the backend, basically just add a `try {...} catch(e) {...}` block at the backend instead of frontend. And for the results you are returning, you can do something like `data = {found: true, result: 'whatever result it is'}` or `data = {found: false, result: undefined}`

Comment: I dont really get this. But what am talking about is the Front end when return the result. If result found, it display the result. Now if no result is found which means is now error how will I display it at the front end, Please take a look at the later part of my code.Thanks for the reipies, really appreciate it.

Comment: Take a look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-meninsky-71g7b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you! if the result is not found it responded, But the problem is that if the result is found it throw this error

     Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.data.message is undefined

How can I please solve it also!

Comment: do `if (result.data.message && result.data.message.text)`

Comment: Thank you so much! it working perfectly now! I appreciate your time and effort.

Can you share with me your twitter handle to get in touch with you,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using await, try this;

```
const fetchAdvices = axios.get(`${API_URL}${searchQuery}`)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
        setAdvices(result.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        // handleError(error);
    });
```